# Rails 3 dropdown select boxes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, drop-down-menu, css-selectors

I am working on a simple intranet application made with Rails 3.1.

I have a model for links which has the following fields:

```
name:string
url:string
colour:string
```

I have put the colour attribute into a class in the view, like so:

```
<a href="linkaddress" class="<%= link.colour %>">Link Name</a>
```

At the moment in the new link form I just have a simple form input in which the user can type anything and it will become the href class as expected.

What I would like to do is create a dropdown list of preset options, these options are simply red, green and blue (as an example). As this seems fairly simple, I don't think there is any need for a helper.

I have read a few other questions and answers on SO and they seem to show examples where you have the name followed by an ID number. I just want to have the code below:

```
<select name="colour">
 <option value="red">Red</option>
 <option value="green">Green</option>
 <option value="blue">Blue</option>
</select>
```

I'm sure this is simple but I can't get my head around it. I've read the Rails API info and the select_for_tag has confused me!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just use a standard select element in your form to set the colour variable:

```
<%= f.select :colour, options_for_select([["Red", "red"], ["Green", "green"]], @link.colour) %>
```

Comment: Perfect, just what I wanted. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Where Colour is the name of your model for your colours and f is the form builder object:

```
 <%= f.collection_select :colour, Colour.all, :url, :name %>
```

This would be the simplest and most straightforward approach to get a select with the colour's url as the value and the name as the text.  If you want both the name for the value and text, you can change :url to :name as well.

In addition, and for semantics, you'd also probably want to set a @colours collection in your controller and use it rather than calling to the model from your view (to replace Colour.all).

UPDATE: Based on your comment below and if you don't have a model for the collection and simply want to hardcode your select and values, try:

```
 <%= select :your_obj, :linkaddress, [["Red","red"],["Green", "green"],["Blue", "blue"]] %>
```

Comment: That's what's confusing me. There are no colour selections set. I want to hard code them into the form.

Answer (score 3):

You want to use the rails helper, because then rails will take care of moving the data into your model.  so you most likely want something like the following.

```
<%= f.select :colour, ["red","green","blue"] %>
```

[This Page](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#the-select-and-option-tags) can be a bit wordy, but it might help how you're thinking about it.